# Storing id from select in ruby variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm working on a RoR backend for a big mobile app, currently with the admin panel.

I have two models: `Activity` and `Deal`, joined by HMT `ActivitiesDeal`. The join is tested both ways in rails console and works like a charm.

Activity is the model the app is built around, so admins need to be able to add deals to activity from the "Edit activity" form in some intuitive way. 
I tried this for creating activities_deal:

```
<%=select("deal", @deal_id, Deal.all.collect {|d| [d.title, d.id]}, {})%>
<%= link_to "Add", link_activity_deal_path(activity_id: @activity.id, deal_id: @deal_id), method:'post' %>
```

But it doesn't work as I thought. Any ideas on how to send the correct deal_id to link_activity_deal_path? This seems like a problem that has been solved many times, but I can' find anything that fits.

ActivitiesDealsController:

```
class ActivitiesDealsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
    render file: 'public/404.html' and return unless @activity && Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
    @activity_deal = ActivitiesDeal.new
    @activity_deal.activity_id = params[:activity_id]
    @activity_deal.deal_id = params[:deal_id]
    if @activity_deal.save
        redirect_to proc {activity_url @activity}
    end
    render file: 'public/500.html'
end

def destroy
    p params
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
    render file: 'public/404.html' and return unless @activity
    @activity_deal = ActivitiesDeal.where("activity_id == ? AND deal_id == ?", params[:activity_id], params[:deal_id])
    render file: 'public/404.html' and return unless @activity_deal
    ActivitiesDeal.destroy(@activity_deal)
    redirect_to proc {activity_url @activity}
end
end
```

Comment: Please state your question. Please specify, what is the desired behaviour and what’s wrong happened in the current implementation. Please get rid of unrelated code.

Comment: I think the keyword here is *nested form*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by making a form_for outside of the edit page.

If anyone needs the code:

```
 <%= form_for @activity, as: :deal, :url => link_activity_deal_path(activity_id: @activity.id), method:'post' do |f|%>
<%= f.collection_select :id, @deals, :id, :title %>
<%= f.submit "Add Deal", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```